# Como excluir um objeto no .json usando Python?

Tags: python, json, microsoft-excel

Utilizo um sistema de processamento em Excel, no qual utiliza Python para fazer a maioria de suas funcionalidades.

Estou tendo uma dificuldade nessa situação: Quero editar um arquivo .json utilizando Python, em especifico, quero excluir um dos meus "schedule" atualizando o seu respectivo numero. Todas as vezes que tentei nunca deu certo. Segue foto do arquivo .json e o código em Python que eu uso para adicionar e limpar o arquivo respectivamente.

[image: Esse é o arquivo .json que quero manipular]

[image: Esse é o código em Python que uso para adicionar e apagar todos]

Exemplo: No arquivo .json, quero excluir a partir da virgula na linha 32 até antes da virgula da linha 39. (se possível atualizar os números de cada "schadule")

Obs: Dependendo do projeto, esse arquivo .json chega a ter mas de 400 "schadule".

Se eu abrir o .json e apagar manualmente o que eu quero, funciona sem problema nenhum.
Só quero encontrar uma forma de apagar uma parte dele caso eu erre, através de um botão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função que deleta um 'schedule' por identificador. No seu exemplo, vc aponta as linhas [33-39] para deletar, que é representado pela chave/identificador "6". Logo, é só fazer uma função que dado um identificador você remove esse identificador do arquivo. Para manipular arquivos json vc pode utilizar o módulo json do python. Ao abrir e carregar o arquivo com o módulo json, a função deve deletar o identificador passado. Ex:

```py
def delete_schedule(key):
    with open("seu_nome_de_arquivo.json", "r") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        delete data["schedule"][key]
    with open('data.txt', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file)
```

Usei como base este [link](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/)